# WebAPI and Object Parameters With a List(of T)

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI method as below:

```
Public Function PostTestStatus(dto As DTOStatusUpdate) As HttpResponseMessage
```

and the "dto" parameter is defined as this:

```
Public Class DTOStatusUpdate
  Property QueryByNameDTO As QueryByNameDTO 
  Property Tests As ICollection(Of Test)

  Public Sub New()
    Me.Tests = New Collection(Of Test)
  End Sub
End Class
```

tests is just a simple class (strings/integers only)

and i am sending the following json: (which validates as correct)

```
{"QueryByNameDTO":{"email":"atest@here.co.uk","notes":"blahblahblah","Name":"bob"},"Tests":[{"Name":"gsdf","Status":"idle"},{"Name":"gsdf","Status":"idle"}]}
```

My method is never reached because the Collection(Of Test) is not valid/correct
ive tried List(Of Test), IEnumerable(Of Test) and various other combinations none work.

The part i dont get is that if i send the json without the "Test" list my methods breakpoint is reached and the first property (QueryByNameDTO) is all present and correct.

It also works if i change the DTOStatusUpdate class to use just a singular "Test" rather than a List(of Test).

The problem seems to be in the use of a List/Collection/Enumeration(of Test).

What am i doing wrong, ive been at this for hours now and its doing my head in. ive googled and searched and gone round and round in circles trying to find an explanation. The closest i got was regarding adding  to the parameter which then reaches the method and breakpoint but all properties of the parameter are nothing?

I can return a IEnumerable(of whatever) from a webapi method so what am i missing to send one to a webapi method?

**EDIT1**: Having stripped the Test Class down to one field "id" where it worked ok, and building it back up i've narrowed this down to one attribute on one field in that class.

Here are two fields from the test class Status and DNNUserId. 
Status works fine with or without the Required Attribute!
However adding Required attribute to DNNUserId property causes the method not to be called/reached? Taking the required attribute off it works?!?!

Perhaps ive been at this too long because other than string vs integer there is no difference? should the json be formatted differently if an integer is required? can anyone shed any light on this?

```
Private _Status As String
<Required()>
Public Property Status As String
    Get
        Return _Status
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        If _Status <> value Then
            _Status = value
            OnPropertyChanged("Status")
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Private _DNNUserId As Integer
Public Property DNNUserId As Integer
    Get
        Return _DNNUserId
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        If _DNNUserId <> value Then
            _DNNUserId = value
            OnPropertyChanged("DNNUserId")
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and see if it works.

```
Public Class DTOStatusUpdate
  Public Property QueryByNameDTO As QueryByNameDTO 
  Public Property Tests As ICollection(Of Test)

  Public Sub New()
    Me.Tests = New Collection(Of Test)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I thought properties were public by default if no accessor was specified? anyway i tried this and it didnt make any difference.

Comment: You are correct. It is my bad. I knew the code was VB.NET but some how it did not click in my mind. Too much C# coding may be. Any ways, the JSON you have provided is getting bound to the class perfectly. I'm not able to repro your problem. Sorry I couldn't help.